# Structural type to mirror a Java static method

Tags: scala, structural-typing

Given a third party Java library with the call

```
public static Bar Foo()
```

Can I define a structural type to represent this? The following doesn't type match, as it doesn't capture the static nature.

```
val fooBar: { def Foo: Bar }
```

Of course, I can always wrap this call in something else & that's what I'll do if necessary. But, is there a syntax that will define a type for this method?

Answer (score 0):

Scala doesn't have `static` so you can't define it. There are `object` that behave like static but they are not exactly the same.

You may keep trying but you will inevitably end up with `Object is not a value` error.